# set row equal to other row in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Here is the current state of my table:

```
mysql> select * from page;
+----+----------+----------------+------+---------+
| id | title    | body           | page | visible |
+----+----------+----------------+------+---------+
|  1 | my title | my body        | NULL |       1 | 
|  2 | my title | my body edited |    1 |       0 | 
+----+----------+----------------+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want row 1 to contain the values of row 2. Basically, I want to do:

```
UPDATE page SET page.* = (SELECT * FROM page WHERE id = 2) WHERE id = 1;
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: In a comment/post below you say that you'll want to do this "with many different tables".  If you're regularly making identical rows in your database, it might be a sign that you need to rethink how you're storing your data.

Answer (score 8):

> insert into page (id, title, body, page, visible) Select 2, title, body, page, visible

Can be done (in MySQL only) without the DELETE by using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:

```
INSERT
    INTO page (id, title, body, page, visible)
    SELECT 1, title, body, page, visible FROM page WHERE id=2
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        title= VALUES(title), page= VALUES(page), visible= VALUES(visible);
```

However can also done (perhaps better) in an ANSI-compliant way with a self-join:

```
UPDATE page AS page1 JOIN page AS page2 ON page1.id=1 AND page2.id=2
SET page1.title=page2.title, page1.body= page2.body, page1.page= page2.page, page1.visible=page2.visible
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with two statements.

```
Delete from page where id = 2
insert into page (id, title, body, page, visible) Select 2, title, body, page, visible
from page where id = 1
```

Alternately, you could join the table back on itself and explicitly update the values. i.e. set  derivedtable.field = page.field

Comment: Deleting then recreating a row as opposed to just updating it isn't really a good idea..

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to write a stored procedure that would look at the metadata for the table in question, and construct the necessary SQL to update one row from another without having to hardcode it. (Get the set of all columns, loop over it, etc.) But that seems like an awful lot of work.

You could also do the same thing in application code (PHP, Perl, C#, or whatever), if you can't accomplish it with sprocs.